# Rails 4: Can I pass a partial into a partial?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, partials

I found a lot of info on how to pass data, json, strings etc into a partial but I would like to pass a partial into another partial. Here is my code so far:

**My parent.html.erb**

```
  <%= render partial: 'shared/faq_question', locals: { 
    id: '1',
    question: 'A question I\'m asking', 
    answer: 'A string answer that does\'nt cause any problems'
    } %>

  <%= render partial: 'shared/faq_question', locals: { 
    id: '2',
    question: 'A question that requires an HTML answer', 
    answer: 'THE PARTIAL SHOULD GO HERE'
    } %>

</ul>
```

**My _faq_question.html.erb**

```
<li id="question<%= id %>">

  <a href="#question<%= id %>" class="ca" data-activate="#question<%= id %>" data-method2="toggle">
    <i class="close-icon"></i>
    <span><%= question %></span>
  </a>

  <div>
    <p><%= answer %></p>
  </div>

</li>
```

So far, so good. The second question above has content that has HTML content in it like so:

```
<%= render partial: 'shared/faq_question', locals: { 
  id: '22',
  question: 'A question that requires an HTML answer?', 
  answer: "<span>Something</span>
    <ul>
      <li>Some foo</li>
      <li>Some bar</li>
      <li>Content</li>
    </ul>

    <span>Keep in mind:</span>
    <ul>
      <li>There is more </li>
      <li>This is great</li>
    </ul>

    <span>Please note:</span>
    And another sentence".html_safe
  } %>
```

I would like to replace **answer** with a partial.

**My _answer.html.erb partial**

```
<span>Something</span>
<ul>
  <li>Some <%= foo %></li>
  <li>Some bar <%= foofoo %></li>
  <li>Content <%= bar %></li>
</ul>

<span>Keep in mind:</span>
<ul>
  <li>There is more </li>
  <li>This is great</li>
</ul>

<span>Please note:</span>
And another sentence
```

I tried adding in the partial snippet and use html_safe but this breaks and comes up with errors when the browser renders that there are syntax errors, which is because the answer partial doesn't get escaped correctly.

**What I've tried:**

```
answer: <%= render partial: 'shared/faq_question' %>.html_safe
```

And

```
answer: (<%= render partial: 'shared/faq_question' %>).html_safe
```

And

```
answer: "<%= render partial: 'shared/faq_question' %>".html_safe
```

What do I need to do to escape the partial correctly and get it to render in the browser?

I also want to pass in data into the second partial to replace the following variables:

```
<li>Some <%= foo %></li>
<li>Some bar <%= foofoo %></li>
<li>Content <%= bar %></li>
```

foo

foofoo

bar

Any help or ideas in the right direction would be highly appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are already in ruby block, no need for additional erb-tags, try

```
answer: render(partial: 'shared/faq_question')
```

Comment: Oh so very simple! Can you tell, I have no experience with Rails? ;) Thanks a lot!